# Input.value returns NaN on display

Tags: javascript

First of all, I know there is such a title, I read it but it didn't work (or I couldn't do it). I have 2 inputs in my HTML page and one of them works perfectly and the other one gives NaN error.

```js
const startTimerButton = document.getElementById("startTimerButton");
const timerDisplay = document.getElementById("timerDisplay");
let timerInput = document.getElementById("timerInput");
let startminute;
let timer;
let time = startminute * 60;
let hours;
let minutes;
let seconds;

startTimerButton.onclick = function() {
  if (timerInput.value != "") {
    startminute = Number(timerInput.value);
    startTimer();
  } else {
    alert("değer girin.");
  }
};

function startTimer() {
  timer = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
  document.querySelector("#timerInput").classList.add("d-none");
  document.querySelector("#timerDisplay").classList.remove("d-none");
  console.log(parseInt(startminute));
}

function updateTimer() {
  hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
  minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
  if (minutes >= 60) {
    hours++;
    minutes -= 60;
  }

  time--;
  hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  timerDisplay.textContent = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}

function resetTimer() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  hours = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  seconds = 0;
  timerDisplay.textContent = `0${hours}:0${minutes}:0${seconds}`;
}
```

```html
<div id="time-panel" class="rounded shadow me-2">
  <div id="time-panel-buttons" class="d-flex mt-4 justify-content-around align-items-center">
    <a href="#" class="btn ms-5" id="stopwatchButton">Stopwatch</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn me-5" id="timerButton">Timer</a>
  </div>
  <div id="stopwatch-container" class="d-none mt-5 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div id="stopwatch">
      <span id="stopwatchDisplay" class="text-center mb-3 ms-1">00:00:00</span>
      <div class="buttons mt-2 ms-2">
        <button id="startStopwatchButton" class="btn green p-3 mx-1" onclick="startStopwatch()">
          Start
        </button>
        <button id="stopStopwatchButton" class="btn green p-3 mx-1" onclick="stopStopwatch()">
          Stop
        </button>
        <button id="resetStopwatchButton" class="btn green p-3 mx-1" onclick="resetStopwatch()">
          Reset
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="timer-container" class="mt-5 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div id="timer">
      <span id="timerDisplay" class="d-none text-center mb-3 ms-4">00:00:00</span>
      <input id="timerInput" type="number" class="form-control mb-3 ms-1" />
      <div class="buttons mt-2 ms-2">
        <button id="startTimerButton" class="btn green p-3 mx-1" onclick="startTimer()">
          Start
        </button>

        <button id="stopTimerButton" class="btn green p-3 mx-1" onclick="stopTimer()">
          Stop
        </button>
        <button id="resetTimerButton" class="btn green p-3 mx-1" onclick="resetTimer()">
          Reset
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

I used `parseInt()` after entering the value but the result is the same. Although the value appears as a number in the console output, it gives an error in the timerDisplay section. I am new to JS, I may have missed something.By the way it works when I enter the `startingmunite` value from within the application. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `let time = startminute * 60;` - you haven't defined `startminute`. `undefined * 60`  is not a number. You should also get in the habit of debugging your code with `console.log()` to help find where a variable has unexpected values.

Comment: I only see one input in the HTML: `<input id="timerInput" type="number" class="form-control mb-3 ms-1" />`

Comment: You need to assign `time` after you do `startminute = Number(timerInput.value);`

Comment: The whole page is too long and not relevant to my problem.  Thanks for your suggestion, it worked. @Barmar

Comment: @AndyRay I will take your suggestion into consideration. thank you

Comment: If the second input is not relevant, then why mention that you have 2 inputs?

Comment: You logic is incorrect. You have two event listeners. Variable declared will not work as you are expecting.

Comment: @Barmar i wanted to mean, i dont have problems about taking inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning `time` before you assign `startminute`, and never update it when the user clicks on the Start button. Assigning a variable using an expression doesn't mean that it will evaluate that expression every time the variable is used (it's not like spreadsheet equations).

Move the assignment of `time` inside the event listener, so it uses the value of `startminute` read from the input.

```
const startTimerButton = document.getElementById("startTimerButton");
const timerDisplay = document.getElementById("timerDisplay");
let timerInput = document.getElementById("timerInput");
let startminute;
let timer;
let time;
let hours;
let minutes;
let seconds;

startTimerButton.onclick = function() {
  if (timerInput.value != "") {
    startminute = Number(timerInput.value);
    time = startminute * 60;
    startTimer();
  } else {
    alert("değer girin.");
  }
};
```